# Fill tool creating large output files from sections of a Raster

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, memory

[image: Image of data from one ofthe clipped rasters, uncompressed size does not match what the size in my drive says]

(This raster information for one of the clipped rasters)

I have a raster image representing a landscape that is about 1.3Gb. I clipped the raster into 31 sections which vary in size from 10Mb to 40Mb. Whenever I use the Fill tool on a section, the output raster is 1.3Gb (like the whole original raster). This is too much memory to process. Why is the Fill tool creating such a large output file for just a section of the original raster? Is there a way to reduce this size?

Edit: Additional Information

The Rasters were clipping using the methods in this previous question

[Clip raster using shapefile into multiple rasters using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84969/clip-a-raster-using-a-shapefile-into-multiple-rasters)

Edit 2: Python Script changing the mask environment before using Fill (It works, but still provides the 1.3Gb "Fill" Raster)

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace = (r"Workspace\Path")

    for i in range (31):

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("shapefile","featurelayer" + str(i),'"FID"='+str(i)) 

        arcpy.env.mask = ("featurelayer"+str(i))

        arcpy.ClipManagement(“fullextentraster”, “#”, raster +“clip”+str(i)+ “.tif”, “file_name” + str(i), “0”, “ClippingGeometry”) 

        outFill = Fill(“rasterclip”+str(i)+“.tif”)
        outFill.save (r“Save\Location\Folder\rasterfill”+str(i)+ “.tif”)
```

Edit 3: Python Script changing the processing extent environment before using Fill

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace = (r"Workspace\Path")

    for i in range (31):

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("shapefile","featurelayer" + str(i),'"FID"='+str(i)) 

        arcpy.env.extent= ("featurelayer"+str(i))

        arcpy.ClipManagement(“fullextentraster”, “#”, raster +“clip”+str(i)+ “.tif”, “file_name” + str(i), “0”, “ClippingGeometry”) 

        outFill = Fill(“rasterclip”+str(i)+“.tif”)
        outFill.save (r“Save\Location\Folder\rasterfill”+str(i)+ “.tif”)
```

Comment: What method did you use to clip the original raster into 31 sections?  What values surround your clipped raster cells (e.g. NoData, 0, etc.).  Is the original raster extent the same as the clipped rasters?  What is the bit depth (e.g. 8 bit unsigned) of the original raster, the clipped rasters and finally the processed rasters after the Fill operation?  If you could include answers to these in your post, we would appreciate it.

Comment: Unexpected changes in raster size, position, or resolution are almost always due to not changing default settings in the processing environment.  Please tell us precisely what your settings were when you performed the Fill operation.

Comment: What do mean by "Settings"?

Comment: Thanks for updating your post JC11.  What values surround the clipped raster images?  Try running the `Fill` operation using a mask (located in the environment settings) of your specific area of interest.

Comment: Please refer to the [other threads that explain about ArcGIS raster environment settings](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=raster+environment+arcgis).

Comment: @whuber: My settings were default, I did not change anything.

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks for idea about extracting by mask. I am going to try this as opposed to using Clip (Data Management) on my raster images using my area of interest.

Comment: JC11: And that, I believe, is *exactly* your problem.  You need to change the settings when clipping out a raster so that ArcGIS does not fill up the rest of the output with NoData values to match the extent of the original raster.  Before you go any further, please study the [ArcGIS help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#/The_analysis_environment_of_Spatial_Analyst/005900000019000000/) covering this topic.

Comment: JC11, Extract by mask would be worth trying, however, I was referring to setting the "mask" environment within the fill tool.  More here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w0000001t000000.  @whuber is referring to setting the output extent in the environment settings: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000009000000

Comment: @Aaron, I've tried extract by mask using a feature class and setting the mask enviornment to the same feature class before using Fill. Neither were able to avoid having the output come out as 1.3Gb. I will post in my question a python script I wrote that would perform this task. Maybe there is something wrong along the way.

Comment: @Whuber I have read your provided references and agree with you that the output extent is the most likely source of the error. I changed the processing extent in Geoprocessing>Environments to the area of interest using a shapefile and ran the Fill tool. The output raster was still 1.3Gb. I have provided a rough script of what I am doing in edit 3. Is there a way to set the extent in python? If setting the processing environment did not work, what could be the error? Thank you.

Comment: The constant size of the output is very convincing evidence that you did not succeed in changing the output extent. A [search of our site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=python+arcgis+extent+arcpy) turns up many threads about this topic, but few of them give satisfactory answers. Dan Patterson's answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10313 might be the most helpful, but look through some of the others if you can.

Comment: Thanks again whuber, ApplyEnvironment in theory is the script that would help set the output extent. I've tried it out, but the output raster is still 1.3Gb. This question is evolving into a different question. I will continue to research my options and see if the community can help edit my script to set the output extent.